# GET http://localhost:5000/error 404 (Not Found)||Unable to connect to API

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, express, web-scraping

`I am trying to make an API call that gets information about a product from amazon using their productId with express.js, using scraperApi
While running, It shows an error:

"{"name":"RequestError","message":"Error: Invalid URI "$%7BbaseUrl%7D&url=https://www.amazon.com/dp/$%7BproductId%7D"","cause":{},"error":{},"options":{"uri":"${baseUrl}&url=https://www.amazon.com/dp/${productId}","simple":true,"resolveWithFullResponse":false,"transform2xxOnly":false}}"

instead of the products data
while inspecting, it shows the following errors,

Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.

HERE IS THE CODE:

```
const express = require('express');
 const request = require('request-promise');

 const app = express();
 const PORT= process.env.PORT||5000;

 const apiKey ='[sensitive information]';
 const baseUrl ='http://api.scraperapi.com?api_key=${apiKey}&autoparse=true';


 app.use(express.json());

 app.get('/',(req,res ) =>{
res.send('Welcome to Dentel API project');
 });

 //GET Product details
 app.get('/products/:productId',async(req,res)=>{
     const{productId}= req.params;
     try{
         const response = await request('${baseUrl}&url=https://www.amazon.com/dp/${productId}');
         res.json(response);
     }catch(error){
        res.json(error);
     }
 });

 app.listen(PORT,()=>console.log('Server running on port ${PORT}'));
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use **backticks** but used single-qoute.

Chang below line

```js
const response = await request('${baseUrl}&url=https://www.amazon.com/dp/${productId}');
```

To

```js
const response = await request(`${baseUrl}&url=https://www.amazon.com/dp/${productId}`);
```